# Create list using a Workflow

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a list of projects called "Project Reference." I want to create a new project list (for project tracking) called "[Project Name] Tracking" when someone adds a new project to Project Reference. This results in two questions:

1. Should I be creating a new project list to track a project when someone creates a new project? It seems like I should, but maybe there is a better way.
2. How do I create a list (preferably via SPD considering my poor programming skills) when a user adds a new item (I cannot find a workflow action that accomplishes this task)?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Can you give us more of an idea for the requirments of the second List?  You are correct that there is no action in SP Designer to create a new List.  Certainly a New List item or copy List item is avaialable.  Do you really need a secondary List?  This all depends on the requirements for tracking projects.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the reply. I "think" that I want a secondary list. The idea is that the first list lists all of the projects and the second list lists all of the tasks for a single project. I intend to use the Project template for the second list, and I am using a custom list (with about 100 columns) for the first list.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create new lists with SharePoint Designer workflows.

A standard way to track a project/task hierarchy would be to use two lists:

- list of projects
- lists of tasks, with a lookup column that points to the projects list

You can then use grouping, Web Part connections or other grouping/filtering techniques to display the tasks.

If you are on SharePoint 2010, you could also use a project list to create a summary-task hierarchy. But I am not sure if SPD workflows will let you choose under which summary folder you can create a task.

Comment: Hi Christophe. Thanks very much for your feedback. I considered using a single Project Tracking list to complement the Project Reference list. With that, I can just add new list items to Project Tracking when a user adds a new project to Project Reference. In that scenario, I would need to enable to the user to click a link in Project Reference to see a filtered view of Project Tracking that displayed only the desired project's tracking information. Can I build a workflow in SPD that filters one list based on the "clicked" item in another list?

Comment: Daniel, try this: go to the Project Tracking list; filter it manually for a given project using the column filter; look at your page URL to see how it was changed to include the filter (FilterField1, FilterValue1); in the workflow, use a string variable to build that URL.

Comment: Thanks, Christophe! I understand the URL filter and making it dynamic (e.g. [Title]). But I am thoroughly lost on two points. First, how do I build the workflow to edit an item to include the link (when I try to set a hyperlink field to a value by clicking the elipses, it comes up with an Edit Hyperlink dialog instead of a string builder dialog)? Second, once I get the hyperlink to work and the Project Tracking view opens with the appropriate filter, how do I retain the filter if the user switches views?

Comment: Not sure how to deal with this. For such needs, I usally use text fields, not hyperlink fields. As for the views, the filter would be lost (as expected), unless you customize the page with code to forward the filter to the next view.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with SharePoint 2013 you can use custom 3rd party activities.

We recently developed the new activity [Create list](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/docs/activities-description/#CreateList). It allows to create the SharePoint list by custom template.